# [Android]Google Gson crashing app

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, gson

i am using gson in my android app to save alarms in form of my NDAlarm class.
But when i try to convert my array of NDAlarms to json the app freezes and the garbage collector goes crazy!

What is happening?

My saving code in my activity:

```
private void SaveAlarms()
{
    Log.d("NewDay", "Saving Alarms");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();

            String temp = gson.toJson(_Alarms.toArray(), NDAlarm[].class);

            _Editor.putString("Alarms",temp);
            _Editor.commit();
            Log.d("NewDay", "Saved Alarms");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I call SaveAlarms in my activity´s pause override.

My NDAlarm Class:

```
public class NDAlarm {

private long _AlarmTime = 0;
private PendingIntent _AlarmIntent = null;

public NDAlarm(long time, PendingIntent intent)
{
    _AlarmTime = time;
    _AlarmIntent = intent;
}

public long get_AlarmTime() {
    return _AlarmTime;
}

public void set_AlarmTime(long _AlarmTime) {
    this._AlarmTime = _AlarmTime;
}

public void set_AlarmIntent(PendingIntent _AlarmIntent) {
    this._AlarmIntent = _AlarmIntent;
}

public PendingIntent get_AlarmIntent() {
    return _AlarmIntent;
}

public DateTime ToDateTime()
{
    return new DateTime(_AlarmTime);
}
```

}

I have heard about something called the "circular reference" problem with gson but i don´t know how to identify it or how to fix it.

Please Help.

Comment: Post your crash log as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487717/android-converting-arraylist-to-gson-runs-out-of-memory) is similar.

Your issue is probably something to do with trying to serialise a PendingIntent object. To stop it being serialised you could declare it as transient:

```
private transient PendingIntent _AlarmIntent = null;
```

...then set it after deserialising it. Or since all you'd be storing in that case is the alarm time, it might be better to just add that to your shared preferences and skip out any of the Gson stuff.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I have started to store a PendingIntent id instead of the actual PendingIntent.